# Как узнать объем жесткого диска компьютера батником?

Tags: cmd, bat, hdd

Как узнать объем памяти жесткого диска сколько всего, сколько занято, сколько свободно в гигабайтах. Причем реальную а не виртуальную

Например:

Диск - С, Всего - 100gb / 100%, Занято - 60gb / 60%, Свободно - 40gb / 40%

Диск - D, Всего - 500gb / 100%, Занято - 300gb / 60%, Свободно - 200gb / 40%

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
.txt


    @echo off
    echo.>%0.txt
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set err=100
     
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%i in ('2^>nul ^
    WMIC LogicalDisk ^
    WHERE "DriveType='3'" ^
    GET FreeSpace^, Name^, Size^') do (
     
      set sFreeSize=%%i
      set sFreeSizeOf=%%k
     if NOT 1%%j==1 (
        rem echo %%j %%i %%k
        set /A Free=!sFreeSize:~0,-9!
        set /A Size=!sFreeSizeOf:~0,-9!
        set /A Procent=!Free!*100/!Size!
        set ah= 
        if !Procent! LSS 50 (
          set ah=***ACHTUNG*** 
          if !Procent! LSS !err! set err=!Procent!
        )
        echo !ah!Free space %%j: !Procent!%%. Free !Free! Gb of !Size! Gb >>%0.txt
      )
     
    )
    type %0.txt
    pause
    exit /b !err!
    endlocal
```

-> .bat
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл [туть](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread810530.html)

Comment: По моему этот код не правильно вычисляет память. У меня Диск С - 232гб а свободно 118гб. А код выводит что Диск С - 250гб а свободно 126гб

Comment: @HasanovNavruz всё так, нашел на просторах, хорошее решение. Исправил